# Construir uma lista não-ordenada com content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

Como construir uma lista contendo sublistas usando o `content_tag` do Rails?

Usando o método no Helper não funciona.

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li>Item1
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#>Link1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#>Link2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#>Link3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Com esse código você consegue criar a lista:

```
def li_with_link(link_text, link_url)
  content_tag :li, link_to(link_text, link_url)
end

def ul_with_lis
  content_tag :ul, class: 'menu' do
    content_tag :li do
      "Item1" + li_with_link("link1", '#') + li_with_link("link2", '#')
    end
  end
end
```

Obs: Se sua ideia é simplificar, melhor usar ERB mesmo!

Dê uma olhada na documentação do método também: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Comment: Acredito que a edição da minha resposta está incorreta. Como concatenamos String com  `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`, o resultado será uma String

Answer (score 1):

Essa dica do Rodrigo tem um problema: cada link vai ter uma UL + LI, mas concordo com ele que usar ERB (ou HAML, ou SLIM) é melhor. Se por algum motivo você precisar  fazer isso com ruby, talvez isso ajude:

```
def menu(links = [])
  content_tag :ul do
    links.map do |link|
      content_tag :li do
        link_to link[:label], link[:href]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

chamada:

```
<% links = [] %>
<% links << { label: 'google', href: 'https://google.com' } %>
<% links << { label: 'facebook', href: 'https://facebook.com' } %>
<% links << { label: 'twitter', href: 'https://twitter.com' } %>
<% links << { label: 'logout', href: logout_path %>
<%= menu(links) %>
```